# ¿Cómo remover el tiempo de un tipo de dato Date en Java?

Tags: java, date, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo el siguiente metodo que consulta a la BD y regresa una lista, dentro de esa lista hay tipos de datos **Date** y que me muestran asi la info, lo que quiero es quitar el tiempo en todos los tipos de datos Date

**2021-10-07 00:00:00.0**

este es mi método en el service:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> consultar(String datenIni, String dateFin) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<ValuesDto> listVal = new ArrayList<ValuesDto>();
    try {
        listVal = consultRepository
                .consulValues(datenIni, dateFin);
        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for ValuesDto Data");
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("data", listVal);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

y mi entidad:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ValuesDto implements Serializable {

    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDREGISTRO")
    private Integer idRegistro;

    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "FECHAREGISTRO")
    private Date fechaRegistro;

    
    @Column(name = "FECHACOTIZACION")
    private Date fechaCotizacion;

    
}
```

Comment: ¿Quitar el tiempo en qué objeto exactamente y en qué contexto? ¿De qué herramientas o API o versión de Java dispones? ¿Qué has investigado y/o intentado y qué problemas y/o errores tienes? Hay varias formas de hacer esto, por tanto, conviene que des más detalles del contexto para que obtengas una respuesta adecuada a tu situación.

Answer (score 1):

Como recomendación inicial te diría que de ser posible evalúes el cambiar la implementación de Date por LocalDateTime que trae muchas mejoras para el manejo de fecha y hora, continuando con la soluciona tu problema hay 2 formas simples de eliminar el tiempo:

1. Auxiliándote de la clase Calendar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(removerTiempo(new Date()));

}

public static Date removerTiempo(Date fecha) {
    // Creamos la instancia inicial
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Cargamos la fecha la variable calendar
    calendar.setTime(fecha);
    // hacemos set 0 a las propiedades de tiempo
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // Utilizamos getTime() para retornar nuevamente una variable tipo Date
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

1. Utilizando la clase SimpleDateFormat:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creamos el la variable con el formato de fecha únicamente 
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {
        // Ahora utilizamos el formateador y convertimos la fecha a un String "dd/MM/yyyy" 
       // que es sin tiempo y después  el String lo convertimos a Date nuevamente
        System.out.println(formatter.parse(formatter.format(new Date())));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```